# Converting floating point value to string using gcvt(), but when there are no decimals the whole number printed out ends in a dot

Tags: c++

Just hopefully a simple question about the gcvt() function.
Printing out **buffer** as a result of gcvt(32.000,10,**buffer**), results in "32."
Any way I can get rid of that annoying dot after the 32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get gcvt to not do that - you can remove it afterward with

```
if ((p=strchr(buffer,'.'))
    *p='\0';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) As it usually is with people here, once I posted this question I immediately found a solution. Just using **sprintf(buffer, "%f", float_value);** does the same thing and does not have the dot problem, gcvt is depreciated for a reason.. Thank you so much for your time and response!

Answer (score 0):

As usual after posting took me 10 mins to figure out a solution....
gcvt is depreciated and I was set on using that because after hours of something not working this helped it work.
Anyway, the best way to do this is to use sprintf(buffer, "%f", float_value);
Literally does the same thing and no dot at the end!

Comment: Not "depreciated" - the word you are looking for is "deprecated". They mean quite different things (not even sure "depreciated" is really a word).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Isn't it the opposite of "appreciated"? ;-)